# Copy static class member to local variable for optimization

Tags: c++, optimization

While browsing open source code (from *OpenCV*), I came across the following type of code inside a method:

```
// copy class member to local variable for optimization
int foo = _foo; //where _foo is a class member

for (...) //a heavy loop that makes use of foo
```

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269874/performance-difference-between-accessing-local-and-class-member-variables) on SO I've concluded that the answer to whether or not **this actually needs to be done or is done automatically by the compiler may be compiler/setting dependent.**

My question is if it would make any difference if `_foo` were a `static` class member? Would there still be a point in this manual optimization, or is accessing a static class member no more 'expensive' than accessing a local variable?

*P.S. - I'm asking out of curiosity, not to solve a specific problem*.

Comment: Make a test case, measure and compare, and/or read the assembly.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't trust myself enough in C++ to write the correct test case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing a property means de-referencing the object, in order to access it.

As the property may change during the execution (read threads), the compiler will read the value from memory each time the value is accessed.

Using a local variable will allow the compiler to use a register for the value, as it can safely assume the value won't change from the outside. This way, the value is read only once from memory.

About your question concerning the static member, it's the same, as it can also be changed by another thread, for instance. The compiler will also need to read the value each time from memory.

Comment: I don't think that this is true. Rather, the opposite is true: Unless you (explicitly or implicitly) cross a memory barrier, the compiler can assume that the value didn't change.

Comment: Memory barriers are not implicit.

Comment: Locking a mutex implies a membar.

Comment: Atually, I'm positive your claim is wrong. When using multiple threads, you have to assume that they are executed by different CPUs, too. Since modern CPUs have at least one level of cache, accessing the RAM is not direct but done through the cache by default. That means that if thread A writes a value to address X, and thread B reads a value from the same address without any further synchronization, it will not get the value previously written. Since you need sync anyway to make things work cross-thread, you don't have to worry about those things that are not synced.

Comment: Sure, never worry about synchronization... That's surely a good advice. Why don't just you test and see by yourself?

Comment: And a final note, whether it's thread safe or not was not the question. We were talking about performance here, not synchronization.

Comment: Your snide remark isn't helpful and you misrepresent what I wrote, too. Further, you started making claims about multithreaded accesses. Now, again: Unshared data doesn't have to be synced, obviously. Shared, read-only data doesn't need to be synced either (please ask if this is not clear). For shared, read-write data, just doing a fetch from the according address is not enough, you must take the caches of different CPUs into account, which requires e.g. mutexes or atomics.

Comment: Since we're here in the context of a loop, taking maybe quite some time, how can one be sure that data will not be synced until you've exited the loop? Your loop may even take some scheduling cycles, so I don't think you can make such assumptions...

Comment: I actually have tried understanding what you could have meant, but the message didn't come across. What assumption are you talking about? Do you perhaps mean "committed to RAM" when you say "synced"? Even if that is what you meant, I have no clue if it relates to anything I wrote before. Just in case that is what you mean, if you have multiple threads and CPUs with caches, you can't be sure when a write actually takes place. This exactly is the reason you have to take care of these things explicitly, which is called synchronization.

Answer (score 4):

I think a local variable is more likely to participate in some optimization, precisely because it is *local* to the function: this fact can be used by the compiler, for example if it sees that nobody modifies the *local* variable, then the compiler may load it *once*, and use it in every iteration.

In case of member data, the compiler may have to work more to conclude that nobody modifies the member. Think about multi-threaded application, and note that the memory model in C++11 is multi-threaded, which means some other thread might modify the member, so the compiler may not conclude that nobody modifies it, in consequence it has to emit code for *load* member for every expression which uses it, possibly multiple times in a single iteration, in order to work with the updated  value of the member.

Answer (score 0):

In this example the the _foo will be copied into new local variable. so both cases the same.
Statis values are like any other variable. its just stored in different memory segment dedicated for static memory.

Answer (score -1):

Reading a static class member is effectively like reading a global variable. They both have a fixed address. Reading a non-static one means first reading the this-pointer, adding an offset  to the result and then reading that address. In other words, reading a non-static one requires more steps and memory accesses.

Comment: I'd appreciate constructive feedback instead of mere downvoting.